# Angular 2- How to place one child component as overlay of another child in parent component

Tags: angular

In my code I have a video chat component where I have two child components app-subscriber and app-publisher.

```
<div *ngIf="session">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="well">
           <app-subscriber *ngFor="let stream of streams" [stream]="stream" [session]="session"></app-subscriber>
        </div>
        <app-publisher [session]="session">&nbsp;
        </app-publisher>
        <button class="btn btn-default"><a href="#" routerLink="/chat"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i> &nbsp; End Call</a></button>
 </div>
```

How i can place the publisher component as overlay of subscriber component

Comment: Can you more clarify your question?

Comment: You can simply swap the child component tags. Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9ufdz

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make publisher as an overlay to subscriber by adding position relative to app-subscriber and position absolute to app-publisher. Anyway thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div *ngIf="session">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <app-publisher [session]="session">&nbsp;
      </app-publisher>
      <div class="well">
       <app-subscriber *ngFor="let stream of streams" [stream]="stream" [session]="session"></app-subscriber>
    </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default"><a href="#" routerLink="/chat"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i> &nbsp; End Call</a></button>
  </div>
```

Simply paste publisher component above subscriber component. Are you facing any issue by doing so?

Comment: what i want actually is publisher component as an overlay above subscriber component in video chat